# Loading every second new json file in html without reloading the whole page

Tags: javascript, python, html, api

I am pretty new in this stuff and tbh I have no idea of javascript, so sorry for the maybe stupid question. I created two python-scripts. The first one is a flask API. Here I generated a root in '/'. When the request method is 'put', it is taking the data from my python simulation script, which is creating some random data, and storing it locally as a JSON file on the computer. The 'get' method is loading and returning this JSON file. My problem now is, that I like to create something like a dashboard, I like to display on the one hand the data in real-time and on the other hand I like to plot this data. For displaying the data I created a javascript, which is requesting the JSON file and displaying it as values. But somehow, every time I'm overwriting the JSON-file the whole page is reloading and my live plot is not working because of this.
How can I suppress this and refresh just the values instead of the whole page?

javascript for loading the values from the request

```
async function getISS() {
  const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000");
  const data = response.json();
  const { Flow, Pressure, Solubility, Temperature, Timestamp, Valve } = data;
  document.getElementById("sol").textContent = Solubility;
}
getISS();
```

python script for creating the simple API:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'PUT'])
def create_record():
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        record = json.loads(request.data)
        with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(record, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
        return 'Done'
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        if 'data.json' in os.listdir():
            with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                data = json.load(f)
            return data
        else:
            return '<body>Data is not available!</body>'

app.run('127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=False)
```

I would like to display the values in specific divs without reloading the page, every time a new JSON file is available.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Testbench</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/Logo.png" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Smooch+Sans&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img class="Logo" src="images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" />
    <h1 class="website_title">Testbench</h1>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="all_sensors">
        <p class="box_title">Sensors</p>
        <div class="sensors">
          <p class="sensor_class">Temperature in °C</p>
          <div class="value" id="temperature"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sensors">
          <p class="sensor_class">Pressure in bar</p>
          <div class="value" id="pressure"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sensors">
          <p class="sensor_class">Solubility</p>
          <div class="value" id="solubility">
            <p>
              <span id="sol"></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="testsection">
        <p class="box_title">Test</p>
        <select name="test" id="choosetest">
          <option value="testscene">Choose Test</option>
          <option value="testscene">Cyclus</option>
          <option value="testscene">Some Other Stuff</option>
          <option value="testscene">Again Some Other Stuff</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="live_plot" id="graph"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="testchoice"></section>
    <script>
      const api_url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000";
      async function getISS() {
        const response = await fetch(api_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        const { Flow, Pressure, Solubility, Temperature, Timestamp, Valve } =
          data;
        document.getElementById("sol").textContent += Solubility;
      }
      getISS();
      function rand() {
        return Math.random();
      }

      var time = new Date();

      var data = [
        {
          x: [time],
          y: [rand()],
          mode: "lines",
          line: { color: "#80CAF6" },
        },
      ];

      Plotly.plot("graph", data);

      var cnt = 0;

      var interval = setInterval(function () {
        var time = new Date();

        var update = {
          x: [[time]],
          y: [[rand()]],
        };

        var olderTime = time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() - 1);
        var futureTime = time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() + 1);

        var minuteView = {
          xaxis: {
            type: "date",
            range: [olderTime, futureTime],
          },
        };

        Plotly.relayout("graph", minuteView);
        Plotly.extendTraces("graph", update, [0]);

        if (cnt === 100) clearInterval(interval);
      }, 100);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML? The reason it's overwriting is because you are overwriting the content of the element with id "sol". You either need to append this data to the element or store the content in an variable, append the new data to that variable and then overwrite the textcontent of "sol".

Comment: HTML is shared. :)
So what do I have to change in my script to refresh just the value?

Comment: You should make sure your `<script>` blocks follow *after* the elements they try to modify, that way it's guaranteed that the browser actually knows those elements. Currently this is only "kind of" the case, because the HTTP request takes a while and the page has *probably* finished rendering before the result is there. But moving all your `<script>` tags to the end of the document (before the `</body>`) is a good idea nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to get this working is to change

```
document.getElementById("sol").textContent = Solubility;
```

to this, which will take the textcontent and add on the next bit of data. This is appending the data each time to that element rather than overwriting it each time.

```
document.getElementById("sol").textContent += Solubility;
```

Comment: I changed it, but the second javascript is still reloading every time a new value is coming. But the whole page is not rendering anymore.
I also tried to do it as @Tomalak mentioned, I moved all scripts at the end of the body but this issue is still there.

Comment: What do you mean by second javascript? You only call getISS() once in that example provided?

Comment: The second one is the plotly.plot script, which is reloading every time the new value is created. It is the last part in script block, beginning with var time = new Date ();

Comment: @Lysapala Oops that's my bad. I edited this part out, because you were only talking about the first script in your original question, and I wanted to streamline the code sample. Please feel free to move the relevant bit back in, but try to concentrate on the script that causes the issue you see.

Comment: @Tomalak no problem, I thought maybe there is also an issue in my HTML script. As I mentioned, I am very new to programming HTML and javascript. I inspected the elements and I see, that all elements are still reloading.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. My problem was that I had the JSON file in the same directory as my HTML. Somehow this led to the problem that the script was refreshing all the time. I moved my python scripts to another location and now it's working. Thank you anyway for your help guys. :)